# Is it legal to record Internet audio streams?

Tags: united-states, copyright, is-x-legal

Is it legal to record an Internet audio stream (sometimes incorrectly called "Internet radio") for later playback for private use? Does it matter if you delete immediately after listening vs. saving as a music library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes

[Time shifting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_shifting) for personal use was ruled fair use by SCOTUS in 1984.

Comment: Thank you! Is it necessary to delete the recordings after listening to them?

Comment: @Someone, yes.  "Delete after listening" is what distinguishes time shifting from a permanent (and copyright-violating) copy.